# Docker python: can't open file '//api.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I am using docker with two containers. One for html and the other one for my fastapi.

When I want to compose my docker, the html container works well but for composing fastapi app, I receive this error in docker:

```
python: can't open file '//api.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3-onbuild

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["python", "api.py"]
```

Here is my docker compose:

```
version: '3'  

services:
  app-service:
    build: ./app  
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app # mount point
    ports:
      - 5001:80  # host:container

  website:
    image: php:apache  # pulling image from DockerHub
    volumes:
      - ./ui/templates:/var/www/html # mount
    ports:
      - 5000:80  # host:container
    depends_on:
      - app-service
```

Here is the structure of the files I have in the main directory:

```
C:.
|   docker-compose.yml
|
+---app
|   |   api.py
|   |   Dockerfile
|   |   requirements.txt
|   |
|   \---service
|           main.py
|
\---ui
    \---templates
            download.png
            index.html
```

Comment: You've placed your Python script in `/usr/src/app/api.py`, but you're running `python api.py`. By default your current working directory is `/`, so as the error says, there is no such file or directory. You could either run `python /usr/src/app/api.py`, or you could set your `WORKDIR` to `/usr/src/app`.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for your comment. I added WORKDIR /usr/src/app to the dockerfile and still receiving the same error.

Comment: @larsks I also added this: CMD ["python", "/usr/src/app/api.py"] and it didn't help.

Comment: 1. I can't reproduce the problem you're asking about. Using your `docker-compose.yaml`, your `Dockerfile`, and your example directory layout, it all works just fine for me. Python is able to run `api.py` without a problem.

Comment: 2. The `python:3-onbuild` image doesn't appear to be maintained; the latest version of that image is only Python 3.6.6, released back in June 2018. You probably want to use a newer image (and handle requirements installation explicitly in the `Dockerfile`).

Comment: @larsks I changed python:3-onbuild to python:3.10 but still having the same error.

Comment: @larsks python:latest doesn't work as well